# The number of times one needs to sample with replacement to cover a fraction P of a set

Tags: probability

Take the expression $(1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^x)$, which is the expected fraction of elements one samples from a set of $n$ elements, sampling with replacement (and uniform probability) $x$ times.

Provided some $n$, how do we analytically solve for $x$ s.t. $(1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^x) \geq P$?  It appears that $\frac{x}{n}$ converges to a fixed value as $n \to \inf$.  Is this true?  If so, how do we find it without relying on numerical methods?

Comment: Your expression $(1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^x)$ is always less than $1$, so how can this be the expected number of unique elements?? Also, to even have the slightest nonzero chance of covering a portion $P$ with $x$ samples one needs $\frac xn\geq P$, and this requires $x\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. So obviously $x$ cannot.

Comment: @Marc von Leeuwen Sorry, I meant that the expression was the fraction of a set of n elements covered after sampling with replacement x times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
  1 - \left(1 - \frac 1n\right)^x \ge P\\
\iff \left(1 - \frac 1n\right)^x \le 1-P\\
\iff x \cdot \log\left(1- \frac 1n\right) \le \log(1-P)\\
\iff x \ge \frac{\log(1-P)}{\log(1 - \frac 1n)}
\end{align*}
So the smallest such $x$ is $x(n) = \left\lceil\frac{\log(1-P)}{\log(1 - \frac 1n)}\right\rceil$ and $x(n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ (as $\log$ is continuous and $\log 1 = 0$).

Answer (score 1):

The inequality can be rewritten as
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^x\le 1-P.$$
We first solve the **equation**
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^t= 1-P.$$
Take the (natural) logarithm of both sides. 
We get
$$t\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\log(1-P).$$
Thus
$$t=\frac{\log(1-P)}{\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}.$$
Presumably we want $x$ to be an integer. The smallest integer $x$ for which our inequality holds is $\lceil t\rceil$.

It is clear that $x\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$. However, something interesting happens if we look at $\frac{x}{n}$. We look instead at the closely related $\frac{t}{n}$, which has the same limit. We have
$$\frac{t}{n}=\frac{\log(1-P)}{n\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}.$$
Note that the denominator $n\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is equal to 
$\log\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)$. But $(1-1/n)^n\to e^{-1}$ as $n\to\infty$, so the denominator approaches $-1$. It follows that as $n\to\infty$, $\dfrac{t}{n}$ (and therefore $\dfrac{x}{n}$) approaches $-\log(1-P)$.

Comment: Nicolas Sorry, I meant that the expression was the fraction of a set of n elements covered after sampling with replacement x times.