# Number of samples with replacement to reach expected coverage of population under non-uniform sampling

Tags: probability, sampling

I am interested in finding the number of times $n$ I need to draw with replacement from a population of size $N$ such that the expected proportion of the population seen is at least $P$. From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219379/the-number-of-times-one-needs-to-sample-with-replacement-to-cover-a-fraction-p-o), I have that for uniform sampling,

$$n = \left\lceil\frac{\log(1-P)}{\log(1 - \frac 1N)}\right\rceil.$$

Is it possible to extend this to the case of non-uniform sampling, for example when items are drawn according to a power-law distribution or one resembling it?